# optimize web scraping using wget

Tags: bash, web-scraping, wget

I am using wget to download a huge list of web pages(around 70,000).I am forced to put a sleep of around 2 seconds in between successive wget.This takes a huge amount of time.Something like 70 days.What I would like to do is to use proxies so that I can significantly speed up the process.I am using a simple bash script for this process.Any suggestions and comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First suggestion is to not use Bash or wget. I would use Python and Beautiful Soup. Wget is not really designed for screen scraping.

Second look into spreading the load across multiple machines by running a portion of your list on each machine.

Since it sounds like bandwidth is your issue you can easily spawn up some cloud images and throw your script on those guys.

Comment: I downloaded Beautiful Soup.But I don't think I need that.My bottle neck is downloading the web pages into my machine.Once I have the pages I can extract the info I want with just a grep command.I am not very familiar with python.Does it have any libraries to optimize the actual collection of data(getting web pages to your PC.)Bandwidth is not my issue.At least not the issue that is causing the present problem.The site which I am scraping is somehow is protected against DoS(I assume,hence I am force to wait.).I could think of deploying across multiple machines or on a cloud.

Comment: Well the other reason I was recommending python was so that you could not have to keep executing processes and recreating connections. A python script might be able to reuse connections thus more server friendly. ... I hope your not doing anything bad :)

Comment: thanks.will dig into python.and No,I am not doing what you think I am. :)